# How do I allow a non-root user to set the timezone via d-bus?

Tags: permissions, systemd, d-bus, timezone

I am writing an application on an embedded Linux device that sets the Timezone as a non-root user.  To boil things down to the essence, I want to execute this:

```
dbus-send --system --dest=org.freedesktop.timedate1 --print-reply /org/freedesktop/timedate1 \
        org.freedesktop.timedate1.SetTimezone  string:'America/New_York' boolean:false
```

But when I do that, I always get this error:

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Permission denied
```

### Other info

The device is running with SELinux *disabled* and polkit is not installed or running.

I have a d-bus configuration file `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.timedate1.conf` as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>
  <policy user="root">
    <allow own="org.freedesktop.timedate1"/>
    <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.timedate1"/>
    <allow receive_sender="org.freedesktop.timedate1"/>
  </policy>
  <policy user="ceres">
    <allow own="org.freedesktop.timedate1"/>
    <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.timedate1"/>
    <allow receive_sender="org.freedesktop.timedate1"/>
  </policy>

  <policy context="default">
    <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.timedate1"/>
    <allow receive_sender="org.freedesktop.timedate1"/>
  </policy>
</busconfig>
```

It is the `ceres` user that I want to grant the ability to change the timezone.

### My questions

1. How do I enable a specific non-root user to set the Timezone via this D-Bus interface?
2. More generally, how do I determine the cause for a "Permission denied" error?
3. `journalctl --follow` shows nothing when this happens.  Where should  I look instead?

Comment: Perhaps allow that user sudo access to the command.

Comment: There is a whole lot of dbus configuration in `/etc/dbus-1/`, and you can see
the sources
[here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/tree/main/src/timedate) including
`org.freedesktop.timedate1.policy` but I
don't have further info on how you need to modify this XML.

Comment: The policy file is for polkit which is not installed on this device.  My `.conf` file is very similar to the one in the link you posted.  I have edited my question to include it for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it with `dbus` configuration only, as Lennart explains in the link below...
You'd need either `polkit` or (as suggested in commments) `sudo timedatectl...`
See this bug report:

[*dbus methods: fall back to checking Linux capabilities when compiled without PolKit*](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/11034)